# Javascript - and infinite loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have this snippet of tracking (below)
I was looking at why it's possibly making 4 calls each time you click "addToCart.gif".
i added "console.log()" to each if case - and noticed it's looping.

Is this because it's calling the same function before the function has ended?
is there a better way of doing this that you can advise?

Thank you so much!

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var href = location.href
if(href != "" && href.indexOf("/product/") > 0){

   mboxDefine("clicked-addToCart","clicked-addToCart")
   var count=0;

   function addToCartClickTracking(){
      if(typeof jQuery == 'function' && jQuery(".add-to-cart[src*='addToCart.gif']").length > 0 && count < 10){
         console.log("adding click tracking")
         jQuery(".add-to-cart[src*='addToCart.gif']").click(function(){
            mboxUpdate("clicked-addToCart")
         });
        count=10;
      } else {
         console.log("trying again")
         count++;
         setTimeout(addToCartClickTracking,400);
      }
   }
   addToCartClickTracking();
}
// ]]>
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: In your loop `count <= 10` instead.

Comment: It's not calling the same function "before the function has ended", it's queuing up a future call to the same function with setTimeout(). The else case has no condition to stop the pseudo loop, so if the if condition isn't met the else will keep happening forever.

Comment: Are you trying to wait until jQuery is loaded before adding the click event handler? This seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Check this line, the other code seems good, the only possible issue I see is that this line always returns false.

```
  if(typeof jQuery == 'function' && jQuery(".add-to-cart[src*='addToCart.gif']").length > 0 && count < 10)
```

Also the call `setTimeout(addToCartClickTracking,400);` wouldn't make a problem as its supposed to run only when the other if consition is false

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I agree the problem is using both the `SetTimeout` AND the `addToCartClickTracking();` Its calling a timeout function, and then calling the function again, which calls the Timeout function and the function which... You get the point...

I think deleting the setTimeout, or better yet, replacing addToCartClickTracking(); with it should fix your issue.

Frankly I don't see the point of the recursiveness. You could really delete all of it, and just use

```
jQuery(".add-to-cart[src*='addToCart.gif']").click(function(){
            mboxUpdate("clicked-addToCart")
         });
```

That handles everything you are trying to do. The only benefit with yours I could see is that yours can handle dynamically added elements, which you could do like this:

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".add-to-cart[src*='addToCart.gif'], function(){
                mboxUpdate("clicked-addToCart")
             });
```

Some Other (minor) Suggestions I see:

> Use $ = jQuery (unless there is a reason not to)
>
> Don't Check if jQuery exists every single time (You could set this a variable if you truly need it)
>
> href != "" && href.indexOf("/product/") > 0 -- These can't be
>       different if href exists, indexOf will throw an error even if href    doesn't exist, no need to Check Twice
>
> I also feel the checking of the pages shouldn't matter, but I don't know how your website works so I can't say much on that.

So in the end my suggestion would be to change the code to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var href = location.href
var isProductPage=href.indexOf("/product/");
if(!isProductPage){//Do Something if you are on the wrong page}
$(document).on("click",".add-to-cart[src*='addToCart.gif'], function(){
                    mboxUpdate("clicked-addToCart")
                 });


</script>
```

I apologize if I misconstrued the point of your code, and I hope my tips maybe of some help to you. Good Luck.